# Unix: How to execute a command from one server into another server without logging in?

Tags: unix

when we logged in one server and if we want to execute a command in some other server without logging into that server?

Comment: Without logging in? How would that work? You can setup ssh to login automatically, using certificates, but you cannot execute commands without logging in. That would be a major security hole.

Comment: i think its possible to run command.

Comment: The question is probably more appropriate on serverfault, and I'd assume it's been asked there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set up a user that the command should be executed as (Please, do *not* use `root`!)
2. Use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to create a public-private key pair for that user *on the machine from where you want to initiate the command*
3. Copy the public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (append to the file if it already exists)
4. Run the command as shown by ssmir: `ssh [user@]host command

I've also used this for running automated jobs on other machines that are initiated by a cronjob on the client. For the user I set up very specific accounts that only do the job in question.

You might want to disable password login for that user, too.

It' possible to repeat the procedure for multiple client machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ssh:

```
ssh ... [user@]hostname [command]
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

still need to use ssh keys.  try slogin.  slogin is one of the ssh tools, it will log you in, run your command, give you the output (if any), and drop you out back to your local systems shell.
example:

```
[jhorne@pd-2njg6j1FC17 ~]$ slogin remoteserver01 ifconfig bond0
CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
Kernel 2.6.18-308.8.1.el5 on an x86_64

bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:4D:A2:01:C2:5A  
          inet addr:10.88.254.22  Bcast:10.88.254.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe01:c25a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:251815947 errors:0 dropped:8807 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:284849025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:118687664470 (110.5 GiB)  TX bytes:231265992006 (215.3 GiB)

[jhorne@pd-2njg6j1FC17 ~]$
```

use slogin -q if you want to avoid the login banner.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [rsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell)